# Shift focus with arrow keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to navigate through all the focusable elements on my webpage with the arrow key. So when the down-key is pressed the focus should shift to the focusable element beneath the current focussed element. You get the idea for the other arrow keys, when there is not a focusable element to shift to, the focus should remain the same.

This is what I got so far:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){    

if (e.keyCode == 37) { //left

   var offset = $("*:focus").offset();

   var allElements = $("#container").find('a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]');

   var arr = jQuery.makeArray(allElements);

   var topLeft = offset.left
   var minus = topLeft;
   var currentElement = $("*:focus");

   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
   {

      if ( (arr[i].offset().left < offset.left)  // This doesn't work for some reason
        && ((offset.left - arr[i].offset().left) < minus))
      {
        currentElement = arr[i];
        minus = offset.left - arr[i].offset().left;
        topLeft = arr[i].offset().left;
      }


      currentElement.focus();
   }


   alert( "left pressed" );
   return false;
}

// Other Keys
```

});

the idea was to get all the focus-able elements and than pick select the one that is suited for the arrow and shift focus.

I'm not able to get this code to work (it contains a error) and I'm not completly sure it will even work.

Thnx in advance

[EDIT]: I guess I was a little vague. I do not only want to go left and right, but also up and down.

Comment: So, you want to break what the arrow keys normally do (scroll the page in different directions) just on your page, even though other keys (tab and shift-tab) already do the job? For your users' sake I hope you're building a spreadsheet, because I can't see this being a good idea any other time.

Comment: I think the lesser of evils would be to use the left and right key instead of up and down arrow.  Imgur does a good job with this.

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm not sure what OP wants that for, but Tab and Shift-Tab don't go in Up-Down-Right-Left directions, but in a linear way...

Comment: @jadkik94 Yes, I know. This is preferable in 99.9% of all cases.

Comment: @Blazemonger Just pointing out the difference, although I agree that I don't see any usefulness there.

Comment: Try `alert(arr[i].offset().left);` and `alert(offset.left);` inside the loop, and see for yourself what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What I would do is much simpler. Just add a common class among the objects who should have this functionality (f.ex. "move") and use:

```
$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $(".move:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $(".move:focus").prev().focus();

        }
    }
);
​
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ4PJ/

This code is *much* simpler and hopefully has all the functionality you need.

**Just make sure the controls are in the correct order** or this won't work properly.

Comment: May i know if this method will work if tv  remote controle is used instead of laptop arrow keys?

Comment: @user1788736 I don't know, it's a very old and outdated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve that without jQuery?

Comment: @MikeMichaels of course. This answer is 6 years old, now vanilla JS in browser has support for much smarter selectors.

Comment: @Cranio And how exactly can I do it? You don't have to explain everything. I am thankful If you can just point me to the right direction. What should I search for?

Answer (score 3):

After much trial and error, I developed this code that works :

```
function navigate(origin, sens) {
    var inputs = $('#form').find('input:enabled');
    var index = inputs.index(origin);
    index += sens;
    if (index < 0) {
        index = inputs.length - 1;
    }
    if (index > inputs.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    inputs.eq(index).focus();
}

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==37) {
        navigate(e.target, -1);
    }
    if (e.keyCode==39) {
        navigate(e.target, 1);
    }
});
```

right arrow acts as tab

left arrow acts as shift tab

Answer (score 2):

Preview - http://jsfiddle.net/FehKh/ ;)

**html:**

```
<a href='jqwja' class="focusable">jajaj</a>
<a href='jjaasd' class="focusable focused">jajasdaaj</a>
<a href='jjqwea' class="focusable">jajaacasj</a>
<input value='iddqd' name="DoomII" class="focusable" />​
```

**js:**

```
// init
$('.focused').focus();

// actual code
$(document).keydown(function(e){    
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
        if($('.focused').prev('.focusable').length)
            $('.focused').removeClass('focused').prev('.focusable').focus().addClass('focused');
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
        if($('.focused').next('.focusable').length)
            $('.focused').removeClass('focused').next('.focusable').focus().addClass('focused');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented above by checking some articles and stack over flow links

```
jQuery.fn.elementAfter = function(other) {
for(i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
    if (this[i] == other) {
        return jQuery(this[i + 1]);
    }
}
return jQuery;
} ;

jQuery.fn.elementBefore = function(other) {
if (this.length > 0) {               
    for(i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == other) {
            return jQuery(this[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}
return jQuery;
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bkLnq5js/79/

Answer (score 0):

This works great

```
$('p').each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('tabindex', index)
}).on('keyup', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $('[TabIndex="' + Number(Number($(this).attr('tabindex')) + 1) + '"]').focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $('[TabIndex="' + Number(Number($(this).attr('tabindex')) - 1) + '"]').focus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of above solutions worked for me. This one is mine. It look difficult but it's accually real easy. Create `array` of link and change focus using the array `index`. (I needed up/down arrow so keycodes are different). It also works with `dynamicly` added links (cause I needed it this way, that is why I use `on`)

```
$('#links_container').on("keydown", ".link",
    function(e)
    {    

        //start - list of <a>
        var flag = false;
        var smallMeni = document.getElementById('links_container');
        var allElements2 = smallMeni.getElementsByTagName('a'); //.link
        //end

        //start - key down
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {           
            for (var i=0;i<allElements2.length;i++)
            {

                if(flag == true){

                    flag = false

                    allElements2[i].focus();

                    //alert(i)
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( document.activeElement === allElements2[i] )
                    {
                        //alert(i);
                        flag = true;
                    }           
                }

            }
        }
        //end

        //start - key up
        if (e.keyCode == 38) 
        {           
            for (var i=0;i<allElements2.length;i++)
            {

                if ( document.activeElement === allElements2[i] )
                {
                    if (i>0)
                    {
                        allElements2[i-1].focus();                  
                    }
                }           

            }
        }           

        //alert(i);

    }
);
```