# How to find the next and previous element in <li>tree and make it focusable:

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code looks like this

```
<ul role="tablist>
<li role="presentation" tabindex="0">
<a role="tab" href='#' data-toggle="tab">One</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" tabindex="0">
<a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href='#'>Two</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" tabindex="0">
<a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href='#'>Three</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" tabindex="0">
<a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href='#'>Four</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to find the  element and make it focusable whenever arrow key is pressed.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You haven't asked us a question, you haven't said which element ("*the element*") you're trying to find, you haven't shown any attempts at solving your own problem. We're here to help you solve your problem, we're *not* here to do your work for you, for free. Please read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: my bad I didn't mention my solutions, here are the solutions which i tried elem.bind("keydown", function ($event) {
    if ($event.which == 37) {
 var target = $event.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling;     
 $(target).trigger('focus');
    }
    if ($event.which == 39) {
     console.log("right key pressed");
  var target = $event.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
     $(target).trigger('focus');
    }
   });

Comment: i am able to focus <li> element with above coade but not able to do it for <a> which is inside <li> element,if you suggest any other solution it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I got this worked by below code.not sure abt the performance of the code.
 elem.bind("keydown", function ($event) {
    if ($event.which == 37) {
                var target = $($event.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling);
    var x = $(target).children();
                x.focus();
    }
    if ($event.which == 39) {
                console.log("right key pressed");
                var target = $($event.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling);
                var x = $(target).children();
                x.focus();

    }
  });

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much do you spend for finding answers for your problem. But there are few on `Stackoverflow`.

Take a look over this question 
[Shift focus with arrow keys in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088674/shift-focus-with-arrow-keys-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for you:

```
// wait to load DOM
$('document').ready(function() {

    // active li holder
    var active = 0;

    // add keypress listener
    $('body').on('keypress', function() {

        // get the keycode
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

        // check for arrow keys
        if(code == 37) { //left
            active++;
        } else if(code == 39) { // right
            active--;
        }

        // this is the active li element you can process it as per your need
        $('ul li').eq(active);

    });

});
```