# Shift focus onkeydown - JavaScript Only - No jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, focus

I would like to be able to navigate through some of the focusable elements on my webpage with the arrow keys, using JavaScript only.

I found a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088674/shift-focus-with-arrow-keys-in-javascript#11088844). Only thing is, it uses jQuery, which I don't want to use. I was told by the author of that answer that it is possible to achieve the same effect with JavaScript only. I just don't know how, or even what to look for. I'm still a beginner, so I am sorry if it is an obvious question.

This is the jQuery version of what I want to achieve:

```
<input class='move' /><input class='move' /><input class='move' />

$(document).keydown(
    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $(".move:focus").next().focus();
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $(".move:focus").prev().focus();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Yep, it's possible. Check out my answer. 

Comment: Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year! 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It works perfectly! Thanks, mate.

Comment: Yay! Happy holidays! `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following functions:

- `querySelectorAll()` or `getElementsByClassName` for selecting elements.
- `addEventListener()` for binding the event listener.
- `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling` for getting the 
  `previous()` and `next()` elements.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
      if (this.previousElementSibling) {
        this.previousElementSibling.focus();
      }
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
      if (this.nextElementSibling) {
        this.nextElementSibling.focus();
      }
    }
  }, false);
```

```html
<input class='move' />
<input class='move' />
<input class='move' />
```

For more replacement stuff, check out: [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using a custom class to handle the moves.

```js
class MoveHandler {
  constructor() {
    //Get the first element of the list and set it as the current
    //TODO: if the DOM doesn't get updated it is also possible to store the .move HTML elements within this instance
    this.current = document.getElementsByClassName("move")[0];
    
    //initially set the first as focus
    this.current.focus();
    
    //event listener on the window for arrow keys
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.move.bind(this));
  }

  move(e) {
  
    //update the current according to the arrow keys.
    //Check to see if the current has a previous or next otherwise do nothing.
  
    switch (e.keyCode) {
      case 39:
        if (this.current.nextElementSibling === null) return;
        this.current = this.current.nextElementSibling;
        break;
      case 37:
        if (this.current.previousElementSibling === null) return;
        this.current = this.current.previousElementSibling;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Wrong key");
        return;
    }
    this.current.focus();
  }
}

new MoveHandler();
```

```html
<input class='move' /><input class='move' /><input class='move' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to translate each part into pure JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
        document.querySelector(".move:focus").nextSibling.focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
        document.querySelector(".move:focus").previousSibling.focus();
    }
});
```

And then add some catches in case you're trying to access elements which don't exist:

```
if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
    if (document.querySelector(".move:focus").nextSibling) {
        document.querySelector(".move:focus").nextSibling.focus();
    }
}
if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
    if (document.querySelector(".move:focus").previousSibling) {
        document.querySelector(".move:focus").previousSibling.focus();
    }
    document.querySelector(".move:focus").previousSibling.focus();
}
```