# Change focus with arrow

Tags: jquery, html

I have followed [Shift focus with arrow keys in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088674/shift-focus-with-arrow-keys-in-javascript/11088844) , but it doesn't work for me.
Are there other ways to change focus between input fields using tabs?

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $(".move:focus").next().focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $(".move:focus").prev().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>RM Code</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Wh</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Quantity<br>Recipe</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Weight/<br>Mixer</th>
      <th style="width:10%">No of<br>Weighting</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Qty Used<br>Actual</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="rm_code[]" name="rm_code[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="wh[]" name="wh[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="quantity_recipe[]" name="quantity_recipe[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="weight_mixer[]" name="weight_mixer[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="no_of_weighting[]" name="no_of_weighting[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="qty_used_actual[]" name="qty_used_actual[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is [My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ctL547e1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selects "the immediately following *sibling*". In your HTML, the `<input>` elements are not siblings because each one is inside its own parent `<td>`.

However, the `<td>` elements *are* siblings. So you can traverse from the focused `<input>` to its containing `<td>` to the next sibling `<td>` to its child `<input>`.

One method is to use [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to select the current `<td>`, [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next sibling `<td>`, and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the child `<input>`.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    $(".move:focus").parent().next().find(".move").focus();
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $(".move:focus").parent().prev().find(".move").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>RM Code</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Wh</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Quantity<br>Recipe</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Weight/<br>Mixer</th>
      <th style="width:10%">No of<br>Weighting</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Qty Used<br>Actual</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="rm_code[]" name="rm_code[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="wh[]" name="wh[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="quantity_recipe[]" name="quantity_recipe[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="weight_mixer[]" name="weight_mixer[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="no_of_weighting[]" name="no_of_weighting[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="qty_used_actual[]" name="qty_used_actual[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control move" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If your HTML structure might change, consider more specific selectors:

```
$(".move:focus").closest("td").next().find(".move").focus();
```